# Does WordPress require that your submitted theme supports multiple menu levels?

Tags: theme-development

As the title says I'm wondering if WordPress requires that your submitted theme supports multiple menu levels. I can't seem to find any info on this.

However the [Theme Unit Test](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test) does include hierarchical pages. There's no information in the Theme Unit Test if this is required or not.

Comment: Do you mean you want to submit your theme to WordPress Themes directory?

Comment: Yes, indeed! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not required, but if your theme doesn't support multiple menu levels then you should note this in your theme documentation (readme file)